# Want to apply 50% discount on products which cost more than $10

Tags: mysql, sql

The table name is Products and i want to Apply 50% discount to the price of every entry in the Products  table that costs more than $10.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Comment: Your link does not reveal a table matching your description.  Please edit your question, and include sample data and expected output _directly in your question_.

Comment: Click on link and on the right side you'll see Tablename under that click on Products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
Update products set  price  = price/2     where price >10;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. RESPECT

Comment: Now what i need to do is. 1) Use a SELECT to find the llow priced products ($10 or less). 2) Delete all these products. 3) Use a new SELECT to make sure it works

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ProductId,
ProductName,
SupplierID,
CategoryID,
Unit,
CASE WHEN Price > 10 THEN PRICE * 0.5
ELSE PRICE
END AS PRICE
FROM Products;
```